# Swing Application as server to host web services

Tags: java, swing, web-services, plugins, plugin-architecture

I have swing application. Basically I have used "floreant pos" and have customized based on my requirement. Now I want to the same operation what I do from my swing application but in the form of Rest web service.

1. When I start my swing application, there must be web services available to access from mobile app.
2. I need to use same predefined methods for the web services.
3. Simply it's a application as a server.

Above are the requirements, not sure how I can achieve it. Moreover, I need some details of "floreant pos" plugin architecture that they have released in 1.4 version so can anyone help on plugin architecture understanding of "floreant pos"..

Website :- http://floreant.org/
Wiki :- http://wiki.floreantpos.org/

I have been stuck for a long time. Please provide me some solution.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What you need is a server (or better an endpoint listening to a certain address) that provides your REST services. Not sure if you really want to provide those services as part of a GUI (consider aspects like security, availability), but you could embed e.g. a Tomcat server in your application. Btw: IMHO this question is too broad for stackoverflow.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but i cannot use any server like tomcat, I want Rest service which can be access by mobile app, but how can i achieve it that's where i stuck. ?

Comment: I completely understand why you're stuck.  A REST web service converts  a URL into a result.  The process of converting a URL to a result requires a server like Tomcat.  It cannot be done with a Swing application..

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc: Thanks, but any other solution? and any idea regarding "floreant pos" plugin architecture.?

Comment: You built the Swing application using "floreant pos", so you would know better than I.  You need to pull out the model from your Swing application and put them in a web server.  That way, your Swing code can access the web server, and your mobile app can access the web server.  I hope you used the [model / view / controller pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) when building your Swing application.  The model goes on the web server.

Comment: Got some idea, thanks man.